# Python print header response and line number of row for each line in csv import

Tags: python, python-requests, python-import

Ive managed to build a script which gets the response headers of url from an imported text file:

```
import csv
import requests


with open('input.txt', 'r') as url:
    urls = csv.reader(url)
    for row in urls:
        url = " ".join(row)
        resp = requests.head(url)
        print('%s %d' % (url, resp.status_code))
```

This works fine and outputs the following:

```
example.com/url-one/ 200
example.com/url-two/ 200
example.com/url-three/ 404
```

However, i want to also print the line/row number next to each row e.g:

```
1. example.com/url-one/ 200
2. example.com/url-two/ 200
3. example.com/url-three/ 404
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `enumerate`:

```
for row_number, row in enumerate(urls, start=1):
    url = " ".join(row)
    resp = requests.head(url)
    print(f"{row_number}. {url} {resp.status_code}")
```